# MSAL Distributed Token Cache record keys?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I've recently realized that the MSAL Distributed Token Cache, at least when used with Redis, defaults to use as the token cache key, the "HomeAccountId" for the user. This is a combination of the uid and utid claims for a B2B user (home tenant oid and home tenant ID), but the oid and tid claims for a local user. These two GUIDs are concatenated together with a period separating them.

My question is this: assume I have a SaaS application and tenant A is a customer, and tenant B is a customer. Users in tenant B are also guests in tenant A. Now when one of those tenant B users authenticates to tenant B, their cache token key will be "[B.oid].[B.tid]". When they later access tenant A and authenticate there, the cache token stored in my Redis instance will have a key "[A.uid].[A.utid]", but the actual string values will be identical. The 2nd login will overwrite the first cached token. When they go back home, the incorrect token will be retrieved and havoc will result. I can't control this key without overriding the MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapter implementation (i.e., this is Microsoft's preferred behavior).

I frankly assumed that the cache token key was always "[oid].[tid]", regardless of whether you were a local user or a B2B guest.

As I've worked to mitigate this (generating the correct key to retrieve a token enabling back-end, long-running processes to execute OBO the user), this scenario occurred to me. I'm hoping someone will show me what silly thing I've overlooked here, because the implication isn't awesome. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, I see that the access tokens, id tokens, and account metadata all include a "realm" attribute that focuses on the target tenant for the claims. The refresh token doesn't have this because presumably it will always go back to the home tenant first. I see the value in that it allows the same refresh token to be used for all tenants, which reduces the pounding on AAD for redundant authentications.